# Why is this not an array?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a complete Obj-C noob.  In my numberOfRowsInSection, I'm trying to get a list of TV channels associated to a category.  The category and tv channels are setup in a dictionary.  The key is the category and the values are the tv channels.

There is a channels and sectionNames property declared in the interface file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *channels;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *sectionNames;
```

In my numberOfRowsInSection (tableview data source method), I'm trying to return the number of channels associated to the specific category.  But for some reason, channelsInSection doesn't have a count property even though it's an array... ?  So, how do I get the number of elements contained within this variable?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSString *sectionTitle = [_sectionNames objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)section];
NSString *channelsInSection = [_channels valueForKey:sectionTitle];
return (NSInteger)[channelsInSection count];

}
```

For some reason, the last line generates an error.  The error says "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'count'".

But.. it's an array... isn't it?

Please help!

Here is the dictionary:

```
self.channels = @{
                  @"Entertainment" : @[@"SnackableTV", @"Crave", @"Bravo", @"ETVE"],
                  @"Discovery" : @[@"Discovery", @"Discovery Velocity", @"Discovery Investigation", @"Discovery Animal Planet", @"Discovery Science"],
                  @"News" : @[@"CTV", @"CP24", @"BNN", @"CTV News"],
                  @"Sports" : @[@"TSN", @"RDS"],
                  };
self.sectionNames = [[self.channels allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: If `channelsInSection` is supposed to be an array, then why are you declaring it as an `NSString` instead of `NSArray`? And do you really mean to use `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`?

Comment: Because when I declare it as an NSArray, I get an error saying: "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSArray *' with an expression of type 'NSString *' _Nullable'.

Comment: `NSString` has no `count`. It has `length`.

Comment: How would I go about sorting the values within each key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you have declared your `channels` dictionary as having `NSString` values but it in fact has values that are `NSArray`. Update your property to:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> *channels;
```

Then, given your data structure, change:

```
NSString *channelsInSection = [_channels valueForKey:sectionTitle];
```

to:

```
NSArray *channelsInSection = [self.channels objectForKey:sectionTitle];
```

or more simply:

```
NSArray *channelsInSection = self.channels[sectionTitle];
```

Don't use `valueForKey:` unless you have a clearly understood need to use key-value coding.

Comment: Isn't `valueForKey` on `NSDictionary` overridden to do the same as `objectForKey`?

Comment: @Sulthan I don't know but why make such an assumption? But I doubt it could be, otherwise how would something like: `[someDict valueForKey:@"@a.b.c"]` work?

Comment: @rmaddy https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1410210-valueforkey?language=objc _If key does not start with “@”, invokes objectForKey:. If key does start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes [super valueForKey:] with the rest of the key._ I agree that using `objectForKey` or even subscript is better, of course.

Comment: @Sulthan So that proves that `valueForKey:` and `objectForKey:` are not the same.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the fact that an array of strings was being returned but I was not handling it properly.  Thank you, it works!